# switching database with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi is there a way to switch database with mongoose?
I thought I could do it like that:

```
mongoose.disconnect();
mongoose.connect('localhost',db);
```

but it does not work I receive this error:

```
Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
```

I do not know if it is because is asynchronous

Answer (score 6):

As already stated you could do it using `useDb` function :

**Example code :**

```
async function myDbConnection() {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-pauvx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        console.log('Connected Successfully')
        // Here from above url you've already got connected to test DB,
           So let's make a switch as needed.
        mongoose.connection.useDb('myDB'); // Switching happens here..
        /**
         * Do some DB transaction with mongoose models as by now models has already been registered to created DB connection
         */
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error connecting to DB ::', error);
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted to create a complete new connection then you've to try `mongoose.createConnection()`. Just for reference in case of `mongoDB` driver you would use ::

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, primaryDB) {
  // open another database over the same connection
  const secondaryDB = primaryDB.db(SECONDARY_DATABASE_NAME);

  // now you can use both `database` and `database2`
  ...
});
```

**Ref :** [mongoose multiple different connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections), [mongoose useDb()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-useDb), [mongoDB driver switch connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476134/mongodb-express-how-to-switch-database-after-connecting-via-connect)

Answer (score 3):

It is asynchronous.  If you pass a callback function to disconnect and try to connect to the next database in that callback, it will work.

Ex.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test1', function() {
  console.log('Connected to test 1')
  mongoose.disconnect(connectToTest2)
})

function connectToTest2() {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test2', function() {
    console.log('Connected to test 2')
    process.exit()
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, may I ask you, why  I have to call process.exit()?

Comment: There is no need to at all. That was just a little sample script I wrote showing the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The top-voted answer had thrown me in a loop for a few hours. To help the OP and others who may have the same issue, here's my take on the solution:

Suppose you have two databases with the same schema and you want to switch between them on the fly. Let's call them `DB1` and `DB2`. Here's how you can go about doing that:

```js
(async () => {
  const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(url, options);
  
  const getModel = (database) => {
    const dbConnection = connection.useDb(database);
    
    return dbConnection.model('Model', modelSchema);
  };
  
  const Db1Model = getModel('DB1');
  const Db2Model = getModel('DB2');
})();
```

Tested on Node.js v12 and Mongoose v5.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by appending the database name with the database URL. For eg: if you are working with localhost

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:portNumber/xyz_db');

When you connect like this, all your models will be saved in the xyz_db under your model as a collection.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the `useDb` function like so:

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.useDb('Users'); # Change the string to the name of the database you want to use
```

Comment: Although I agree with you, you should add some code to show how OP can use `useDb`.