# MongoDB / Express - How to switch database after connecting via connect()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am using express to connect to my mongoDB:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, database) {

      // How would one switch to another database here?

});
```

I have to connect to the admin database in the first place. After the conenction has been established, i would like to switch the database.

Although i have searched through the official documentation, i was unable to find something that fits my needs.

I am aware of the `MongoClient::open()` method, but i would like to stick to `connect()`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can switch to another database like so:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, database) {
  // switch to another database
  database = database.db(DATABASE_NAME);
  ...
});
```

([docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#db))

**EDIT**: for clarification: this also allows you to open multiple databases over the same connection:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, database) {
  // open another database over the same connection
  var database2 = database.db(DATABASE_NAME);

  // now you can use both `database` and `database2`
  ...
});
```

Comment: Be aware that this [`db` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#db) will "_create a new Db instance sharing the current socket connections_" and that "_the new db instances are related in a parent-child relationship to the original instance so that events are correctly emitted on child db instances_". Moreover "_child db instances are cached so performing db('db1') twice will return the same instance_". So read the documentation carefully before using this in production because closing the connection on one "_child_" db will potentially "close" many db at once.

Comment: You can find implementation details about the hierarchical `close` method in [node-mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/lib_db.js.html#line362) source code.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call `MongoClient.connect` once again, because there is one connection per database. That means, you cannot change the database of an existing connection. You have to connect a second time:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, database) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongourl_to_other_database, function(err, database2) {
        // use database or database2
    });
});
```

Comment: So i have 2 opinions here, which one is the way to go?

Comment: It depends on if you want to use the two (or more) databases in parallel or not. If you switch only once you may take robertklep's solution. If you are siwtching all the time, it might be a better idea to keep the multiple database connections open (my solution).

Comment: @heinob you can open multiple databases over the same connection using the method in my answer. I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I also want to know how to be able to change databases and collections from different functions - can you just create one global instance and "update it", or do you run `mongodb.MongoClient.connect...` each time a function is called (this could be on a click event to get a document from the database etc)?  I'm resisting doing the latter, because it seems like a lot of connecting to do!