# MongoDB as a variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to login and update my mongo database on the server side and having trouble. I'm running on Heroku so I think it might be that I haven't logged in as a user. I've started from this [node login repo](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login) but have changed a few things to get it working on heroku. I try to login in as a variable like so:

```
var MongoDB     = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server      = require('mongodb').Server;    
var db = new MongoDB(dbName, new Server(dbHost, dbPort, {auto_reconnect: true}), {w: 1});
```

When I try to register a user I see a post made in the heroku logs with a 400 response instead of the 200 ok, making me think I'm not getting to the database. I've set my dbName, dbHost and dbPort to the mongolab values but I'm not sure where to login to a user account. I created a session using the URI

```
new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/database' })
```

which wasn't working before I added a username and password which makes me think that's what I'm missing with the variable. So how do I add a username and password to the db variable?

Comment: Heroku has built in mLab support to easily create and connect to a MongoDB from your applications. It does require a credit card on file, but you can choose the free plan for no charges. Would this help or do you need to connect to _a_ specific hosted database?

Comment: I am using mLab yeah and connected on the session with that second code snippit. They show how to [connect with Ruby here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#mongodb-ruby-driver) but I am not sure how to duplicate this with js

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize MongoClient object of 'mongodb' library and supply the auth url as a parameter in connect function

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/database';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 assert.equal(null, err);
 console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
});
```

Comment: I was then calling a variable for a collection      var accounts = db.collection('accounts');  so would I be able to switch out 'db' there with 'MongoClient'?

Comment: you can switch to another database using 'MongoClient' here is the reference of already asked question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476134/mongodb-express-how-to-switch-database-after-connecting-via-connect)

Comment: Well it's not really accessing another database. Basically I'm trying to access collections and export functions [like this](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login/blob/master/app/server/modules/account-manager.js#L15)  which seems to be the old driver for node. Are there examples out there of the right way to do this with the new driver? I haven't been able to find any so far.