# Dynamically passing dbName to mongoose.connect

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

For a MEAN app, I need to pass the dbName depending on the logged-in user. The flow of events is as follows.

1. User logs-in and gets authenticated using an auth specific REST-API.
2. Auth-API returns to Angular the user account data which includes the userSpecificDbName.
3. Thereafter, Angular makes all calls to the app's main REST-API. With all calls to the API, account data is passed and the API shd use the dbName from the account data in the following statement of app.js

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { dbName: <userSpecificDbName> })
  .then( () => {
    console.log('Connection to the Atlas Cluster is successful!')
  })
  .catch( (err) => console.error(err));
```

Is this possible? And how do I pass data in app.js for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to do that, Although keep in mind you would need to open and close connections per request to do that, which is not a regular pattern in Node.js
Normally you would connect to the database once and then fire queries. But in your case, you would disconnect every time after you've sent a response and reconnect and the beginning to the DB.

Alternatively, you could most probably do a useDb call as suggested in the following answer:

[switching database with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862541/switching-database-with-mongoose)

That would help you switch the database.